# where will the log messages stored when device is not connected

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-proguard

I have checked other related questions but could not found related answer.
we can see all our **Log.x**  messages in Logcat but what will happen when device not connected.

I got to know that we can optimize our code through Proguard file. how can we use that to remove all Log messages

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log files are stored in circular buffer in memory. To obtain a copy of buffer I may use:

```
$adb logcat -d > logcat.txt
```

The `-d` option copies all the circular buffer into the text file.

For application specific logs you may try:

```
$adb logcat -d | grep 'com.package.name' -B 100 -A 100 > log_app.txt
```

For the location of Log Files: [Log Locations](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27892/127404)